# How do I access files from my HDD in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, bash

I basically have a lot of files on my hdd, all of the files are of this form,
**2014.C1.012.012 - full name of the file**, all of them with different numbers and names.
   What I would like to do is a webpage, that runs only locally where I have a table divided by **2024 | C4 | 912 | 928 | Description** , and I should be able to search for a drawing, or to select only the C1 files for example.
  For excel I did it by simply using bash to get all the file names with file paths ,and then divide them by categories and then use the hyperlink function.
  What should be the best approach to do this in a webpage ?

Comment: Welcome to SO first take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser sandbox the Javascript that run in the web page: you can't access the "computer" from the "webpage".

You'll have to run a server process to access your data: either a PHP, Python, or a Node.JS based solution.

This server will have the task to browse your data and send the result through the web page.

Answer (score 0):

For the web page you can do it the same way as you did for Excel: Make a Bash script (or Javascript or Python, etc.) that generates the HTML file.

**Another approach** if you want to create a web page to run locally with access to your file system is to use **[Electron](https://electron.atom.io)**. The following is an example web page you can run in Electron to create your file listing. Implementing search features is left as an exercise for the reader.

```html
Loading file listing…

<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 4;
}
</style>

<script>
// Replace this with the path of the directory you want a file listing of.
let directory_path = "."

let file_name_pattern = /^(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(.*?) - ([^]*)/

require("fs").readdir(directory_path, (error, file_names) => {
  if (error) {
    document.body.textContent = "Failed to read directory listing: " + error.message
  } else {
    let table_element = document.createElement("table")
    file_names.forEach(file_name => {
      let match = file_name_pattern.exec(file_name)
      if (!match) {
        return
      }
      let tr_element = document.createElement("tr")
      let cell_index = 0
      while (cell_index++ < 5) {
        let td_element = document.createElement("td")
        td_element.textContent = match[cell_index]
        tr_element.appendChild(td_element)
      }
      table_element.appendChild(tr_element)
    })
    document.body.firstChild.replaceWith(table_element)
  }
})
</script>
```